# locationManager.requestLocationUpdates in BroadcastReceiver Android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, locationmanager, locationlistener

I want to receive user location in background and do some math on it. then send notification to user. I dont know how to manage the `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener)` because of `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity: this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);` need activity and there is no activity in `BroadcastReceiver`.

here is my code:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static LocationManager locationManager;
    private static LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras){
 
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            //do some math on loacation
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // ask for permission

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);


        } else {

                // we have permission!

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

            }
    }


    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

        }

    }
}
```

and MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }



    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("NotificationText", "some text");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 3, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 0, pendingIntent);
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you need to check permission in BroadcastReceiver? Plus IMO BroadcastReceiver is not the place where you should listen to location updates.

Comment: @Trythis because android studio show error on ```locationManager.requestLocationUpdates``` without permission.

Comment: Ask for the permission from your activity. If the user approves of it it should be valid in your broadcast receiver as well.

Comment: @Trythis where I should listen to location updates if I want get location in background and show notification to user?

Comment: Service should be a good place for listening to location updates. And you have to ask required permissions in activity/fragment only.

Comment: @Trythis Can I show notification in service also?

Comment: Yes you can....